# How Change Something in View from Presentation in Prism?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, prism

I want to change something in view(user-control) class from itself Presentation class. For example i want to change button content from Presentation.
@Extra Info: `change something` refer to make a change in Controls-visual or something like that.
so How I do That?

Comment: need more info..what you are trying to do!

Comment: @Malcolm I say `for example i want to change button content and background from Presentation`.

Comment: could we define property in view, and set that from presentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public class XXXPresenter:INotifyPropertyChanged{
private string _buttonContent;
public string ButtonContent{
get{return _buttonContent;}
set{_buttonContent=value; RaisePropertyChanged("ButtonContent");}
}
}

in XAML

As long the DataContext of the button/parent is set correctly any changes to the ButtonContent property in the presenter, should reflect in the UI

Answer (score 1):

@Rev, like you said, I would define a property and bind it to the content property of the button, when you want the content to be changed change th eproperty on the presenter and raise property changed event

Comment: I don't understand. can u help me with code-snip!
Is this possible to change any thing (mean "in controls-visual") in set method!  you make an great help :)